# Can I use REST APIs to remotely launch an application?

Tags: rest

I need to launch an application on a remote system from Java. I know the IP address and the location of the executable batch file on the remote system. I am trying to get it done with PSExec but I can't seem to get it to work due to domain issues.

One suggestion was to use REST API instead. I don't see any info on using REST to launch an application. So anyone who can tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is about resource state manipulation via their representations on the top of stateless communication between client and server. REST is an architectural style and it's protocol independent but, in practice, it's commonly implemented on the top of the HTTP protocol.

---

> Can I use REST APIs to remotely launch an application?

If you can represent your application state as a resource, so you can probably create a REST API to manage it.

---

In practice, your server can provide a set of URLs to locate the resources and their state can be manipulated via HTTP verbs and representations such as JSON and/or XML.

HTTP headers can be used to exchange some metadata about the request and response while HTTP status code should be used to inform the client regarding the status of the operation.

Keep it stateless by storing all session context in the client.